# Python looping through multiple plots

Tags: python, seaborn

everyone. I have a some plots I want to make with Seaborn and it involves a list and a data frame.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Everything works great except that when it generates, it pops up as a single plot and I want to have there be multiple, one for each item in the list.

I posted:

```
#Linear regression
sns.regplot(x='Item #_B01CR1FQMG',y="Positivity",data=a_df)
```

Thanks!
[1]: https://i.ibb.co/fn6s2Ks/sbr.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple plots via matplotlib. To give some inspiration:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.boxplot( your_data, ax=axes[0] )
sns.boxplot( your_data, ax=axes[1] )
```

Another solution is to create each plot individually in a for loop and add `plt.show()` before creating the next one.